# sqlite3 extension functions in C and argument lifetime dynamics

Tags: c, sqlite

Below is a working function extension in `C` for `sqlite3` 3.45.1.
The question is about pointer dynamics and lifetime of input material coming in on `sqlite3_value_blob` and that returned via `sqlite_return_text` and is in the comments at the bottom of the function.
Note that the excellent detailed explanation at
https://sqlite.org/forum/info/5165df43db42e86f6dd027189340099174f24f553b157ecf6e7bc2e40224ff32
has been carefully reviewed.

```c
static void get_some_string_func(
  sqlite3_context *context,
  int argc,
  sqlite3_value **argv
){
    assert( argc==1 );

    // We store struct mytype* in a BLOB so fetch it:                          
    const mytype* mytype_inst = (const mytype*)sqlite3_value_blob(argv[0]);

    // OK, so mytype_inst is a pointer into memory coming in on                  
    // argv[0].  I now call this function which is defined to return             
    // a pointer to a string NOT NECESSARILY NULL TERMINATED inside              
    // (struct mytype*), and that pointer is NOT TO BE freed; note the len is                 
    // passed back via &len:                                                     
    uint32_t len;
    const char* s = mytype_get_some_string(mytype_inst, &len);

    // I now wish to return that string.                                         
    // The absolute safest way is this because a copy of s                       
    // of the appropriate len will be made:                                      
    sqlite3_result_text(context, s, len, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

    // But since s is a pointer into mytype_inst which came in on                
    // argv[0], is there a more efficient way to do this, e.g.?                  
    sqlite3_result_text(context, s, len, SQLITE_STATIC);

    // In other words, what are the malloc/free pointer dynamics                 
    // between                                                                   
    //   sqlite3_value **argv                                                    
    // and                                                                       
    //   sqlite3_result_{text,blob,text16}                               
    // ?  
    // What parts of sqlite3_value **argv have a lifetime that exceeds -- or NOT --
    // processing of the material returned in sqlite3_result_{text,blob,text16}?                                                                     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't count on the pointer returned by `sqlite3_value_blob()` being valid after your function returns. In fact you can't always count on it being valid for the life of the function. From [the documentation](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/value_blob.html):

> Please pay particular attention to the fact that the pointer returned from `sqlite3_value_blob()`, `sqlite3_value_text()`, or `sqlite3_value_text16()` can be invalidated by a subsequent call to `sqlite3_value_bytes()`, `sqlite3_value_bytes16()`, `sqlite3_value_text()`, or `sqlite3_value_text16()`.

Passing `SQLITE_STATIC` as the destructor argument to a result function is a promise that the pointer will remain valid forever (or at least while the current SQL statement is being executed or better yet the lifetime of the database connection). That promise doesn't hold here.

So, using `SQLITE_TRANSIENT` like you're currently doing is the appropriate thing (If your `mytype_get_some_string()` did its own allocation, you could use whatever function frees that memory instead).

Comment: Indeed, the documentation makes that clear; here is an expanded explanation: https://sqlite.org/forum/info/5165df43db42e86f6dd027189340099174f24f553b157ecf6e7bc2e40224ff32
But the question remains:  where is it documented that material set into `sqlite3_result_text/blob` *must* be STATIC, TRANSIENT, or a function pointer to be called when SQLite is finished with that result ('https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/result_blob.html') and using `value` pointers in ANY way for `return` is forbidden?